# How to get relationship of the pivot table with eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

How to get relationship of the pivot table with eloquent.

```
$questions = Question::with('teams')->get();
```

This gets me the list of all questions along with teams.Now i need to get the list of players in any particular team.

Relation in Team Model.

```
public function players()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Player::class,'player_id');
}
```

[Table relations](https://kopy.io/sgqwe)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the nested relation by using the following:

```
$variable = Question::with('teams.players')->get();
```

You can find more information on nested relationships here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading